# Migration from AWS Aurora to a local Postgres 9.6 database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am considering using AWS Aurora, however I am concerned for being locked into AWS indefinitely. So I am wondering how difficult it would be to transfer data from Aurora to my own Postgres database.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very valid concern. Firstly, there is no seamless migration like there is from Postgres to Aurora. Following, needs to be considered:

1. How to do it: You will have to take a dump of your aurora db and then import it into postgres.
2. Because of 1 above; you cannot have concurrent CURD operations running on your aurora during migration. Hence, you need to shut down all products connecting to your aurora till you migrate to Postgres. Hence, there will be downtime.
3. Because of 2 ; Depending on size of your DB; it might take few mins ( few GB of data ) to many hours if you have huge DB.

Hence, you need to consider how much data you have and how much downtime you can live with if you want to migrate back to Postgres.